# How to grep whitespace exclude new-line character?

Tags: grep

Today I need to check which lines of my files containing trailing whitespace. 
And I figured out a solution:

```
grep -Enr --color "\s+$" ./
```

This works well except for those lines containing non-Unix newline characters.

These newline characters will be considering valid match for `\s`.

How to exclude them in OSX `grep`?

Comment: If `\s` is not what you want then use an explicit enumeration of the desired whitespace characters in `[...]`.

Comment: @Janis, how to represent \t in `[ ]`

Comment: @Zen: Try `Ctrl-v` `Tab`.

Comment: @Icd047, nothing happend, I was on OSX

Comment: @Janis, I know I should use [ ], but I don't know how to represent tab in it.

Comment: Have you tried POSIX character class `[[:blank:]]` in place of `\s`? i.e. `grep -En "[[:blank:]]+$"`

Comment: What are "non-Unix newline characters"? Do you mean `\r`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you mean you don't want to match `\r`, you could just specify that you're after a tab or a space and nothing else:

```
grep -P '[\t ]$' file
```

Since you're on OSX, your `grep` won't have `-P`, so you could instead try:

```
grep -E $'\t'"| $" file
```

Alternatively, you can use the POSIX character class:

```
grep  '[[:blank:]]$' file
```

As explained in `man wctype`, the `[[:blank:]]` character class "realizes the isblank(3) classification function" and, as explained in `man isblank`, that is:

```
   isblank()
      checks for a blank character; that is, a space or a tab.
```

Finally, you could also use another tool instead:

```
    sed -n '/[\t ]$/p' file 
    perl -ne 'print if /[\t ]$/' file
```

Comment: @mikeserv thanks, I hadn't seen the OSX bit. `[[:blank:]]` should still work. On my GNU `sed`, `[\t ]` matches a tab or a space, no `\ ` and no `t`. Dunno how that would work BSD sed. I also added a portable grep solution with `$'\t'` for a tab.

Comment: Yeah, it works in a GNU `sed` - a BSD `sed` will get ``\`` or `t` or space. In a POSIX character class all characters stand for themselves - excepting a `-` in the middle of a range or either of `]` or `[` or `^` if it is at the head of the class. Those chars are matched only when positioned specially in the class. The char class *is* the escape usually - so a backslash within the class *as* an escape amounts to a double-negative. Definitely `[:blank:]` will work - that's why I upvoted you. Anyway, considering the problem, the asker should ask a different question.

Comment: Why is the `$` needed here in `grep '[[:blank:]]$' file`?

Comment: @Prometheus `$` is the regular expression symbol for "end of the line". Since the question is asking for _trailing_ whitespace, that means whitespace that is at the end of the line, we need the `$` to only match at the end of the line.